# Text formatting gets destroyed when copy/pasting text into an EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, richtextbox

I have some images and bullet points that I copied and tried to paste inside an `EditText`. 
The images changed to "￼" and no bullet points appeared upon pasting.

The text that was copied was in the following format:

> - "some text"
> - "some more text"

After pasting in the `EditText`, it appears this way:

> "some text some more text".

But if a hyperlink is copied, it remains preserved after pasting.

I want to achieve something like [this](https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2016/12/gmail-on-android-now-supports-rich-copy-and-paste/).

Comment: try Html.fromHtml(String). and pass it to your edit text

Comment: I can capture the paste event but not the string that it pastes, hence not able to provide argument to formHtml()  method .

Comment: I think you should use third party libraries for that.

Comment: Add textWatcher on your EditText and in afterTextChanged Call back do Html.fromHtml()